# How to filter ListItemCollection sharepoint object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-object-model

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                            <Query>
                            </Query>
                        </View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

listItems is getting all 4 files I want to filter list using filename.if filename matches with database table file name then exclude that item from listItems

for example -

```
4 files - 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt
in `database` table if `1.txt and 2.txt` is present then it will match with listItems filename and need to exclude these two items from listItems.
```

above is just an example I have 100's of file which I need to compare using filename and exclude from list if present into database table.

```
So we listItems is having only 2 items - 3.txt 4.txt
```

How can I achieve this without foreach loop ? is there anything I can use like LINQ or CamlQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your caml query to something like this

```
@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
    <Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value>3.txt</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value>4.txt</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
    </Where>                            
    </Query>
</View>";
```

So you can query for items **where** the **FileLeafRef** field **Eq**uals `3.txt` **or** `4.txt`

**But you should check which property contains the file name you are after. In 
my case I needed to change `FileLeafRef` to `Title`**

So for a dynamic list of file names, you can append a new line for each filename before executing the query. Maybe something like

```
// Declare the query string
var queryString = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><or>";

// For each filename, append a new <eq> element containing the relevant details
foreach (var filename in fileNames) { 
    // Process string here, eg check if its in the db or whatever you need to do
    queryString += $"<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value>{filename}</Value></Eq>";
}

// Append the closing tags of the rest of the query
var queryString += "</or><Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: But filename needs to be dynamic and have to compare it with database table values as well. (I ave 100's of file into list)

Answer (score 2):

We can also use LINQ to filter results.

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                      <Query>
                      </Query>
                  </View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var items = listItems.Where(i => i.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString().Equals("1.txt")||i.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"].ToString().Equals("2.txt")).ToList();
```

To build lambda Expressions dynamically, check the article below:

[Build Lambda Expressions Dynamically](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079028/Build-Lambda-Expressions-Dynamically)

Comment: thanks but I have 100's of filename to compare so i will do it dynamically instead of hardcore.

Comment: check the article in my reply to build expressions dynamically base on your datatable from database.

Comment: getting error while execution `listItems.Where` 
{"Specified method is not supported."}

Comment: There is hidden loop over listItems. Also it's bad design. You can reach the query thresholds.

Comment: what we can do ?

Comment: @Neo I think caml is your best bet here - being able to retrieve all the items in one query is definitely a huge bonus

Comment: If you have large data, as Bassie's reply, you can use CAML to achieve it. Build CAML refer to https://shahjinesh11.wordpress.com/2013/12/26/how-to-create-caml-query-dynamically-in-sharepoint/